How to access "storage:ArrayObject:private" property in Beanstalkd library Version 1.13+1+g91c54fc?
I'm using beanstalks 1.13+1+g91c54fc and I have a problem getting private storage array from this output:
Pheanstalk\Response\ArrayResponse Object
(
    [name:Pheanstalk\Response\ArrayResponse:private] => OK
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'transaction_processing'
            [current-jobs-urgent] => 0
            [current-jobs-ready] => 1
            [current-jobs-reserved] => 0
            [current-jobs-delayed] => 0
            [current-jobs-buried] => 0
            [total-jobs] => 1
            [current-using] => 0
            [current-watching] => 0
            [current-waiting] => 0
            [cmd-delete] => 0
            [cmd-pause-tube] => 0
            [pause] => 0
            [pause-time-left] => 0
        )
)

I want to get data from [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array

According to the code at https://github.com/pheanstalk/pheanstalk/blob/1459f2f62dddfe28902e0584708417dddd79bd70/src/Response/ArrayResponse.php#L34 - that object is usable as an array,
So something like var_dump($response['total-jobs']); would output (given that sample data) - '1'.
That code is no longer used in the latest (now v5) version of the library, but you can see the older code at https://github.com/pheanstalk/pheanstalk/tree/v4 - of the code you downloaded.
